Vonage: How to recreate or pass token/refresh token to the @vonage/server-sdk voice api call on nodejs?
I am using the @vonage/server-sdk in my nodejs project and I need to have a session management for the instance that I create for vonage.
This is the code from documentation that I am using to make-call.js for a voice api.
const { Vonage } = require('@vonage/server-sdk');

const vonage = new Vonage({
  applicationId: VONAGE_APPLICATION_ID,
  privateKey: VONAGE_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH,
});

vonage.voice.createOutboundCall({
to: [
{
  type: 'phone',
  number: TO_NUMBER,
},
],
from: {
  type: 'phone',
  number: VONAGE_NUMBER,
},
answer_url: [ANSWER_URL],
})
.then((resp) => console.log(resp))
.catch((error) => console.error(error));

I have a server running say for more than 24hrs and I need to manage the expiry of the vonage voice api that is created. I checked the authentication using server sdk where they have mentioned that we need JWT for voice and we can generate one using @vonage/jwt. I did not understand where to pass the token? or how to handle the refresh token if we get 401(Unauthorized) or Session failed due to a timeout expiration.
Need some help in understanding the flow for regenerating the token/instance of voice api if session expires.
